# firebase update by batches does not work with large dataset

Tags: function, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to populate a feed to almost one million of users upon a content posted by a user with high number of followers using GCP cloud functions.

In order to do this, I am designing to split the firebase update of the feed into numbers of small batches. That's because I think if I dont split the update, I might face the following issues:

i) keeping one million of users feed in memory will exceed the allocated maximum 2GB memory.

ii) update one million of entries at one go will not work (How long it takes to update one million entries?)

However, the batch update only works for me when the batch only inserting around 100 entries per update invocation. When I tried with 1000 per batch, only the 1st batch was inserted. I wonder if this is due to:

i)  time-out ? however I dont see this error in the log.

ii) The array variable , userFeeds{} , keeping the batch is destroyed when the function is out of scope ?

Below is my code:

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var spark = require('./spark');
var user = require('./user');
var Promise = require('promise');
var sparkRecord;

exports.newSpark = function (sparkID) {

    var getSparkPromise = spark.getSpark(sparkID);


    Promise.all([getSparkPromise]).then(function(result) {

        var userSpark = result[0];
        sparkRecord = userSpark;
        sparkRecord.sparkID = sparkID;

        // the batch update only works if the entries per batch is aroud 100 instead of 1000
        populateFeedsToFollowers(sparkRecord.uidFrom, 100, null, myCallback);
    });

};

var populateFeedsToFollowers = function(uid, fetchSize, startKey, callBack){

    var fetchCount = 0;

    //retrieving only follower list by batch
    user.setFetchLimit(fetchSize);
    user.setStartKey(startKey);

    //I use this array variable to keep the entries by batch
    var userFeeds = {};

    user.getFollowersByBatch(uid).then(function(users){

        if(users == null){
            callBack(null, null, null);
            return; 
        }

        //looping thru the followers by batch size
        Object.keys(users).forEach(function(userKey) {

            fetchCount += 1;
            if(fetchCount > fetchSize){
                // updating users feed by batch
                admin.database().ref().update(userFeeds);  
                callBack(null, userKey);
                fetchCount = 0;
                return;

            }else{

                userFeeds['/userFeed/' + userKey + '/' + sparkRecord.sparkID] = {
                        phase:sparkRecord.phase,
                        postTimeIntervalSince1970:sparkRecord.postTimeIntervalSince1970
                }

            }
        });//Object.keys(users).forEach


        if(fetchCount > 0){
            admin.database().ref().update(userFeeds);
        }

    });//user.getFollowersByBatch
};

var myCallback = function(err, nextKey) {

      if (err) throw err; // Check for the error and throw if it exists.

      if(nextKey != null){ //if having remaining followers, keep populating
          populateFeedsToFollowers(sparkRecord.uidFrom, 100, nextKey, myCallback);
      }
};
```